# How use themoviedb.org api in Java

Tags: java, json, httpurlconnection, themoviedb-api

I'm using themovidedb.org api to fetch the movie info in a Java program.

This is the function that i'm using for link my application with themovidedb.org:

```
        url = new URL("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key={MY_API_KEY}");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((con.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
```

This is the response in the console:

```
{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/87hTDiay2N2qWyX4Ds7ybXi9h8I.jpg","belongs_to_collection":null,"budget":63000000,"genres":[{"id":18,"name":"Drama"}],"homepage":"http://www.foxmovies.com/movies/fight-club","id":550,"imdb_id":"tt0137523","original_language":"en","original_title":"Fight Club","overview":"A ticking-time-bomb insomniac and a slippery soap salesman channel primal male aggression into a shocking new form of therapy. Their concept catches on, with underground \"fight clubs\" forming in every town, until an eccentric gets in the way and ignites an out-of-control spiral toward oblivion.","popularity":9.922193999999999,"poster_path":"/adw6Lq9FiC9zjYEpOqfq03ituwp.jpg","production_companies":[{"name":"Regency Enterprises","id":508},{"name":"Fox 2000 Pictures","id":711},{"name":"Taurus Film","id":20555},{"name":"Linson Films","id":54050},{"name":"Atman Entertainment","id":54051},{"name":"Knickerbocker Films","id":54052}],"production_countries":[{"iso_3166_1":"DE","name":"Germany"},{"iso_3166_1":"US","name":"United States of America"}],"release_date":"1999-10-15","revenue":100853753,"runtime":139,"spoken_languages":[{"iso_639_1":"en","name":"English"}],"status":"Released","tagline":"Mischief. Mayhem. Soap.","title":"Fight Club","video":false,"vote_average":8.199999999999999,"vote_count":8430}
```

How can I parse the response to get any attribute (for example: 'original_title', 'relase-date') and use it in the code?

Exists an alternative way to link the program to the database (e.g. using WebResource class)?

Comment: You should rather use an existing java wrapper around the http api like the ones mentioned on https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api/wrappers-libraries - if you want to follow through with your approach you'd need a json parser (or write one). PS: `setDoOutput(true);` is for `POST` and `PUT` requests and `Content-Type` only relevant when a request or reply contains a content body. You might want to set `Accept: application/json` in your request though, telling the server what type you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is formatted using JSON. There are many Java libraries that can be used to parse it. The [built-in method](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html) for Java EE uses [JsonObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html).

```
JsonReader rdr = Json.createReader(con.getInputStream());
JsonObject obj = rdr.readObject();
String title = obj.getString("original_title");
```

On Android, you have [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

```
StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

String inputStr;
while ((inputStr = br.readLine()) != null)
    responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseStrBuilder.toString());
String title = obj.getString("original_title");
```

There are many other libraries capable of doing this, if you have other requirements. There are also some HTTP libraries that make it easy to get JSON like [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) for Android:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key={MY_API_KEY}", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        System.out("title: " + response.getString("original_title"));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

make some variable to collect the json response and parse it.

```
var resp = JSON.stringify(output)
var original_title = JSON.parse(resp).original_title
var release_date = JSON.parse(resp).release_date
```

hope i help you to finish your task